# Is there way was to specify const unichar quoted strings?

Tags: string, unicode, constants

Using xcode, I'm trying to get a const c string into a unichar array by doing the following:

```
const unichar *str = "Test String";
```

but the "Test String" is typed to be (const char *) and produces compiler errors.  Is there way to specify a "Test String" that is of type unichar?

I was hoping for somethig like:

```
const unichar *str = U"Test String";
```

so all the work was done during compile.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know there is no way to do it using a string like that.
You can do it like this

const unichar string[] = {'u','n','i','c','o','d','e'};

But aside from that, i don't know.
But i could be wrong i haven't done very much with this side of c++ :)

Answer (score 0):

If you chose C++11 for C++ Language Dialect under "Apple LLVM compiler" in your project settings, you may use the new C++ character type [char16_t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#New_string_literals%20char16_t) - it's the same size like the unichar type. Then you may initialize string literals in code like that:

const char16_t* str = u"My UTF-16 string";

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string1 = @"Test String";
const unichar *str = (const unichar *)[string1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps `const unichar *str = L"Test String";` would work for you.

Comment: I don't believe the `L` macro generally exists outside of the Microsoft world

Comment: Please ignore my earlier comment. `L` is not a macro. It is a litteral prefix. It does exist outside the Microsoft world. The reason this answer is wrong is because, outside the Microsoft world `L` creates 32-bit characters which are not compatible with `unichar` because `unichar` is 16-bits wide.